# Submit child component from parent component modal ok button in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, angular-components

I am new to angular. I have to two component, one is parent and another is child component. Parent component has a Modal. Child component is a form which is open in the parent component's Modal. Now I would like to know how can I submit the child component form when clicking on parent component Modal's OK button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each time you wanna handle action in child component from parent component like submit you have two choice one create service and subscribe to the actionStatus property

```
export class CtrlActionService {
  private actionStatus = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {}

  //ctrl submit action
  public callAction() {
    this.actionStatus.next(true);
  }
  public getAction(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.actionStatus.asObservable();
  }
}
```

parent.component.ts

```
onClickOkButton() {
  this.ctrlActionService.callAction()
}
```

child.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.ctrlActionService.getAction().subscribe(r => {
    if (r) {
      // your code
    }
  })
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////

or can do another way with call child component method from parent component by create ViewChild

parent.component.html

```
<child #childComponent></child>
```

parent.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('childComponent') childComponent: childComponent;
onClickOkButton() {
  this.childComponent.doAction();
}
```

child.component.ts

```
doAction() {
      // your code
}
```

i only know these two way and hope useful to you